# Fetch/select values from multiple rows into 1 single row in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table with some images in each column.

```
Acd_unq_id  Emp_unq_id  Acd_BImg1   Acd_BImg2  Acd_RImg1  Acd_RImp2  Acd_RImg3  Acd_Active

1          1745     BinaryImg   BinaryImg     NULL      NULL       NULL         1
2          1745        NULL        NULL    BinaryImg    NULL       NULL         1
3          1745        NULL        NULL       NULL      BinaryImg  BinaryImg    1
4          1769     BinaryImg   BinaryImg     NULL      NULL       BinaryImg    1
```

In the above example, I want to get the data in one single column for every unique Emp ID. So according to the above given example, I want the result to be as follows -

```
Acd_unq_id  Emp_unq_id  Acd_BImg1   Acd_BImg2  Acd_RImg1  Acd_RImp2  Acd_RImg3  Acd_Active

1          1745     BinaryImg   BinaryImg  BinaryImg  BinaryImg  BinaryImg     1
4          1769     BinaryImg   BinaryImg     NULL      NULL     BinaryImg     1
```

I have written a query for this -

```
SELECT
(
SELECT TOP 1 ACH_BILL_IMG1 FROM ADVERT_CAMPAIGN_HEADERS INNER JOIN ADVERT_CAMPAIGN_HEADERS
ON ACH_UNQ_ID = ACD_ACH_UNQ_ID WHERE ACD_SOC_UNQ_ID = 1745 AND ACD_IMAGETYPE IN ('H, Q')) as bill_img1

(SELECT TOP 1 ACH_BILL_IMG2 FROM ADVERT_CAMPAIGN_HEADERS INNER JOIN ADVERT_CAMPAIGN_HEADERS
ON ACH_UNQ_ID = ACD_ACH_UNQ_ID WHERE ACD_SOC_UNQ_ID = 1745 AND ACD_IMAGETYPE IN ('H, Q'))
```

I want to get the result using subquery and top 1. But in the above sample query I have written I am getting syntax error....

> *The objects "ADVERT_CAMPAIGN_HEADERS" and "ADVERT_CAMPAIGN_HEADERS" in the FROM clause have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them.*

Please help. Waiting for your reply, experts :)

Comment: If you are trying to do a self join you need to alias at least one of the table references participating in it.

Comment: Hello Martin, Can u help me with this 'select' query..

select
(select top 1 ach_bill_img1) as bill_img1,

(select top 1 ach_bill_img2) as bill_img2,

(select top 1 ach_rcpt_img1) as rcpt_img1,

(select top 1 ach_rcpt_img2) as rcpt_img2,

(select top 1 ach_rcpt_img3) as rcpt_img3,

(select top 1 ach_rcpt_img4) as rcpt_img4

from ADVERT_CAMPAIGN_HEADERS inner join ADVERT_CAMPAIGN_DETAILS on ach_unq_id = acd_ach_unq_id 
where acd_soc_unq_id = 1745

This is still giving me results in multiple rows.... I want to make it into 1 single row...

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
SELECT [Acd_unq_id] = MIN([Acd_unq_id])
, [Emp_unq_id]
, [Acd_BImg1] = MAX([Acd_BImg1])
, [Acd_BImg2] = MAX([Acd_BImg2])
, [Acd_RImg1] = MAX([Acd_RImg1])
, [Acd_RImp2] = MAX([Acd_RImp2])
, [Acd_RImg3] = MAX([Acd_RImg3])
, [Acd_Active] = MAX([Acd_Active])
FROM ADVERT_CAMPAIGN_HEADERS
GROUP BY [Emp_unq_id]
```

Comment: I thought on same lines, but I think max function doesn't work for image data types..

Comment: It works when I test on binary and varbinary types, e.g.

DECLARE @t TABLE(id INT, img BINARY(4000));
INSERT @t VALUES(1,CAST( 123456 AS BINARY(4000)))
, (1,CAST( 5551212 AS BINARY(4000)));

SELECT id, img = max(img)
FROM @t
GROUP BY id

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
`Select xx.Emp_unq_id,Acd_BImg1,Acd_BImg2,Acd_RImg1,Acd_RImg2,Acd_RImg3 from
((select  Emp_unq_id,Acd_BImg1 from yourtab where Emp_unq_id =1745
and Acd_BImg1 is not null)A 
inner join
select  Emp_unq_id,Acd_BImg2 from yourtab where Emp_unq_id =1745
and Acd_BImg2 is not null) B 
on A.Emp_unq_id=B.Emp_unq_id
inner join
(select  Emp_unq_id,Acd_RImg1 from yourtab where Emp_unq_id =1745
and Acd_RImg1 is not null) C
on B.Emp_unq_id=C.Emp_unq_id
inner join
(select  Emp_unq_id,Acd_RImg2 from yourtab where Emp_unq_id =1745
and Acd_RImg2 is not null) D
on C.Emp_unq_id=D.Emp_unq_id
inner join (select  Emp_unq_id,Acd_RImg3 from yourtab where Emp_unq_id =1745
and Acd_RImg3 is not null) E
on D.Emp_unq_id=E.Emp_unq_id)XX`
```

Repet this query for other employee id also...

Comment: Can u help me with this query... This query is not giving me my required o/p, but I want to use the select top 1 only...

select
(select top 1 ach_bill_img1) as bill_img1,
(select top 1 ach_bill_img2) as bill_img2,
(select top 1 ach_rcpt_img1) as rcpt_img1,
(select top 1 ach_rcpt_img2) as rcpt_img2,
(select top 1 ach_rcpt_img3) as rcpt_img3,
(select top 1 ach_rcpt_img4) as rcpt_img4
from ADVERT_CAMPAIGN_HEADERS inner join ADVERT_CAMPAIGN_DETAILS on ach_unq_id = acd_ach_unq_id 
where acd_soc_unq_id = 1745

Answer (score 0):

From your query, I assume there is only one not null value in image columns. Please note that it might give desired result but I don't know from performance point of view. I am also looking forward for other alternate queries on this.

```
;WITH tempCompaignHeaders(ACD_UNQ_ID,Acd_Active) AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Emp_unq_id, Acd_Active FROM ADVERT_CAMPAIGN_HEADERS
)
SELECT
       (SELECT TOP 1 ACD_UNQ_ID FROM ADVERT_CAMPAIGN_HEADERS WHERE Emp_unq_id = t.Emp_unq_id ORDER BY ACD_UNQ_ID) Acd_BImg1,
       Emp_unq_id
       (SELECT TOP 1 Acd_BImg1 FROM ADVERT_CAMPAIGN_HEADERS WHERE Emp_unq_id = t.Emp_unq_id AND Acd_BImg1 IS NOT NULL) Acd_BImg1,
       (SELECT TOP 1 Acd_BImg2 FROM ADVERT_CAMPAIGN_HEADERS WHERE Emp_unq_id = t.Emp_unq_id AND Acd_BImg2 IS NOT NULL) Acd_BImg2,
       (SELECT TOP 1 Acd_RImg1 FROM ADVERT_CAMPAIGN_HEADERS WHERE Emp_unq_id = t.Emp_unq_id AND Acd_RImg1 IS NOT NULL) Acd_RImg1,
       (SELECT TOP 1 Acd_RImg2 FROM ADVERT_CAMPAIGN_HEADERS WHERE Emp_unq_id = t.Emp_unq_id AND Acd_RImg2 IS NOT NULL) Acd_RImg2,
       (SELECT TOP 1 Acd_RImg3 FROM ADVERT_CAMPAIGN_HEADERS WHERE Emp_unq_id = t.Emp_unq_id AND Acd_RImg3 IS NOT NULL) Acd_RImg3,
       Acd_Active
FROM
       tempCompaignHeaders t
```

Comment: Hi Sundeep, this query is giving me same results multiple time.

Comment: Edited my answer but not sure about ACD_UNQ_ID. I picked up top one as displayed in the question.